# while running the docker-compose up it exited error code 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  sonarqube:
    container_name: sonarqube
    image: sonarqube:7.9.2-community
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    container_name: sonardb
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  sonarscanner:
    container_name: sonarscanner
    image: newtmitch/sonar-scanner
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    volumes:
      - sonarvol:/usr/src

networks:
  sonarnet:

volumes:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_logs:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
  sonarvol:
```

Comment: Run docker-compose without -d (interactive mode) and provide the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two containers that are exiting, each with its own cause:

- **sonarqube** initially fails with *max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]*. To solve this, run on your host machine the following command:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

once this is solved, there is a second problem:

- the **sonarscanner** container is launched before **sonarqube** is running, causing this error: *ERROR: SonarQube server [`http://sonarqube:9000`] can not be reached*. To solve this issue, add a restart policy on failure under your scanner, in the compose file:

```
  sonarscanner:
    [...]
    restart: on-failure
```

Once this problem is also solved, the scanner will exit 0(success) hence the execution completes successfully, after printing(which seems to be the normal behavior):

```
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonarqube:9000/dashboard?id=MyProjectKey
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
```